# How can I make an inner join with 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have tables `Professors`, `Inspectors` and `Students` and I want to display in a report associate with table Students, the name of the Inspectors. But, how you can see in table Inspectors I've got only ID's. How can i make an inner join with these 3 tables?
Thanks a lot!

Professors:

```
IdProfessor         
LastName             
FirstName
Adress
```

Inspectors:

```
IdInspector,
IdProfessor
```

Students:

```
IdStudent,
FirstName,
LastName,
Adress,
CNP,
IdInspector
```

Comment: No evidence of any attempt to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Even if it doesn't look like you've been thinking about an answer right now, here is a possible solution for you.
To get students and their corresponding inspectors you can use this query:

```
select s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.Adress, s.CNP, p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.Adress
from Students as s
inner join Inspectors as i on s.IdInspector = i.IdInspector
inner join Professors as p on i.IdProfessor = p.IdProfessor
```